# c: draw layout for the table to console

Tags: c, layout, console, printf

Code works, however I do not know how could I format output correctly to match consistency of the layout (drawing dashes in this case) on any size?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int i=0, k = 0, total_x = 3, total_y = 4;
    char symbol = '+';




    for (k = 1; k <= total_y; k++) {

        // print symbol and row numbers
        if (k == 1) {
            printf("%3c | ",symbol);

            int temp;
            for (temp = 1; temp <=  total_x; temp++) {
                printf("%4d", temp);
            }
            printf("\n");

            for (temp = 1; temp <  total_x*5; temp++) {
                if (temp == 5) {
                    printf("+");
                }
                printf("-");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("%3d | ",k);

        for (i = 1;  i <= total_x; i++) {
            printf("%4d", k + i);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

       return 0;
}
```

Output when total_x = 3, total_y = 4;:

```
  + |    1   2   3
----+----------
  1 |    2   3   4
  2 |    3   4   5
  3 |    4   5   6
  4 |    5   6   7
```

Desired result:

```
  + |    1   2   3
----+--------------
  1 |    2   3   4
  2 |    3   4   5
  3 |    4   5   6
  4 |    5   6   7
```

Output when when total_x = 10, total_y = 4:

```
  + |    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
----+---------------------------------------------
  1 |    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
  2 |    3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
  3 |    4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13
  4 |    5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14
```

Desired result:

```
  + |    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
----+------------------------------------------
  1 |    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
  2 |    3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
  3 |    4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13
  4 |    5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14
```

Any printf function that could help me to print out correctly? Thank you so much!

Comment: `printf("----+--%.*s\n", total_x * 4, "-----------------------------------------------------");`

Comment: @pmg This does not seems to be a nice solution. Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the dashes print prettier like this:

```
printf("----+--");
for (temp = 1; temp <= total_x; temp++) {
    printf("----");
}
printf("\n");
```

**OR** correct the arithmetic in what you did:

```
for (temp = 1; temp <= total_x*4+6; temp++) {
    if (temp==5)
        printf("+");
    printf("-");
}
printf("\n");
```